# Installing Ubuntu with Unity but without the "Big Brother" add-ons and prebundled app cruft

Tags: unity, 13.10, system-installation, netinstall

I just tried the minimal Ubuntu install (a 36MB `mini.iso`) to see if I could get a normal Ubuntu desktop installation with Unity but without the unwanted cruft such as Amazon/Ebay/Music suggestions in search, and the LibreOffice suite, and many other things such as Games, Disc Burner, etc.

However, it looks the "Ubuntu Desktop" selection in the installer still gets me all of those things I don't want.

Therefore, whereas I know these can be uninstalled after the initial setup, I'm still wondering if there's a way to set Ubuntu up without those things from the start, so that only the basic necessities of the Unity desktop are there.

I've tried googling this this but only found directions on how to remove stuff from an already stuffed Ubuntu installation.

Comment: You could do a clean install, remove everything, and create the resulting installable .iso yourself.

Comment: Right; that would indeed help me if I wanted to repeat the installation. I guess I was asking because I feel that it's better to have a clean system right after installation rather than manually removing bits and pieces... Also, removing some spammy lenses and software such as Amazon and eBay cannot even be done via the software center but has to be achieved via some more low level means, which already makes it feel fishy.

Comment: I guess "intuitively" removing some `unity-lens-*` and `unity-scope-*` packages is not a good idea: I don't have the left sidebar anymore.

Comment: I'm not trying to be funny but maybe Ubuntu isn't the right distro for you. Why not try Kubuntu or Xubuntu or even Lubuntu all of which are very configurable.

Comment: I'm actually a Mac user, so I'm kind of used to mature/easy-to-use things; going with any Linux distro for the desktop means already means a lot more more fuss, so I'd rather stick with the most popular option. Also, Lubuntu doesn't have that convenient search mechanism for starting apps (like OS X Spotlight). Kubuntu is alo more of a niche thing (although I know it's better in many ways). Otherwise I'd just go with ArchLinux or some other even more hardcore option.

Comment: Try Linux Mint.  Not exactly as "Mac-like", but definitely less fuss.